# Disable antialiasing when SetResolution on a bitmap C#

Tags: c#, image-processing, bitmap

How can i disable antialiasing when Bitmap SetResolution(xdpi,ydpi) function runs? 
The SetResolution function apply automatically antialiasing how can i prevent the picture of that. 
Here is my code:

```
using (Bitmap newBitmap = new Bitmap(bmp))
            {
                newBitmap.SetResolution(300, 300);
                newBitmap.Save("file300.jpg", ImageFormat.Jpeg);
             }
```

Comment: SetResolution doesn't change "physical" size, nor any pixel. It's just metadata attached to the image. That's probably your way to consume that image later that induce some sort of blur... or isn't it jpeg artifacts ?

Comment: I did'nt use blur or anything after this code i just save it. But it could be jpeg's default process, but the question is how can i disable this?

Comment: There is a `Save` override that accepts encoder parameters that you can use to specify jpeg quality. If you don't want any artifact, opt for a lossless image format, such as png.

Comment: Saving png didn't work. Any other ideas? Thanks